# ~Conditional Probability~ rate(A|B) and rate(not A|B)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Example if:

```
rate(A | B) = 10/180 x 100% ≈ 6%, rate(not A | B) = 170/180 x 100% ≈ 94%
```

Since rate(A | B) < rate(not A | B), is there association between A and B just based on the statements above?

I understand that if **rate(A | B) < rate(A |not B)**, then there is a negative association with A and B. What about **rate(A | B) < rate(not A | B)**?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't mean that there's any negative association. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then it might just be that $\Pr(A)<\Pr(\neg A)$, i.e. $A$ is unlikely. So you can't conclude correlation just from the fact that $\Pr(A|B)<\Pr(\neg A | B)$.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose $\Pr(A | B) < \Pr(\neg A | B)$. Then, using Baye's theorem gives
$$\Pr(B|A)\cdot\Pr(A)<\Pr(B|\neg A)\cdot\Pr(\neg A).$$
So we can see that the inequality might hold regardless of the relationship between $B$ and $A$. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are independent and $\Pr(A)<\Pr(\neg  A)$, then it will hold. But it will also hold if $A$ and $B$ are negatively correlated and $\Pr(A)\leq\Pr(\neg  A)$, as well as if $A$ and $B$ are positively correlated and $\Pr(A)\ll\Pr(\neg  A)$, and other cases, too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

it is always true that 
$$P(A|B)+P(\bar A|B)=1  $$
So you only really have one piece of information.

You need more information, $P(A)$ would be nice.

You can conclude that the events are independent if $P(A|B) = P(A)$

Comment: Thanks! I understood now!